what is this 80's teen tv series? a girl with psychic visions
Does anyone know this tv series from 80's? I don't remember much, but it was a really exciting and a little bit dark story. A girl has short (b&w?) psychic visions about walking in a dark building. Finally she meets in real-life her long ago separated sibling/twin in this building. I think they both carried a similar medallion/ring, and there was somebody/something dangerous in the abandoned building. I think it was either a factory kind of a building or a tower. I'm not sure whether this show was European or American.

Das war es! Thank you so much!! I could only remember the b&w psychic visions about a deserted building and a thunder & tower, and a ring and twins/siblings, and this has been puzzling me for days! It was displayed on TV in Finland in 1988, and it was almost too exciting for me as a kid but I had to see it. Probably had nightmares  Now I'm watching it in youtube!

You seem to be remembering the end of the British children's show The Gemini Factor from 1987. From an online synopsis (sadly, the show isn't even on Wikipedia):

Lee and Leah are both fourteen years old, and share the same birthday. They were both found abandoned as babies - separately - and with each of them had been left a ring depicting half a yin-yang symbol. As soon as they come within a few miles of one another they start experiencing visions of one another's experiences. [...] The series was occasionally reminiscent of parts of Thames' earlier telepathic-boy-meets-girl drama, Chocky's Children, but was rather darker in style and content.

The visions are nearly B&W (the colors are washed out) and they eventually meet on a castle's tower [SPOILER ALERT: this is how it ends]:


 
